# Xcode 6.2 Swift make custom prompt for Location Service

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit

I am wondering if I can display custom alert view to enable GPS and Location Service. And if I can disable default prompt.

Because I received a design where there is a custom prompt for Location Service.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to specify the prompt in your app's `Info.plist` file. The keys for the prompt are `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription`. See the CLLocationManager documentation.

Comment: Yes I know that. But that brings up a default prompt. I am asking if I can disable this default prompt and make my own custom prompt.

Comment: The VALUE parameter for that keys is a custom text, so you get your custom prompt. Just use the text you want to display

Comment: You cant make the prompt custom, its handled by the OS.

Comment: Yes I know that. But this way I can change only text. I want to change whole appearance of the prompt view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is not achievable with the legal methods. When you register for location authentication you ask the operating system for permission, which makes the operating show the prompt which you cannot change.